# UICollection View Cell Displaying Incorrect Data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view which is setup with a UIPageControl. Each cell is one screen. Each cell also contains a table view, which has a header view that displays an image. Each page/cell has a different image. I set the size of the image view to be the size of the image, so each page's image view/table header is a slightly different size.

When scrolling the collection view, however I find that some of the pages are not displaying the correct information. The table view contents were of a previous page, as well is the image and it's size. Essentially, it is not calling my method which sets up the cell. I think this might be because of reusable cells but I don't know how to fix it or turn it off, as I haven't used collection views that much

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Please show code for the collection view delegate and data source callbacks

Comment: It will be better if you put code snippet here. Please check how you add subviews in cell, data source code.

Comment: Are you programatically adding the tableview to the cell?